# Generate unique identifier in data brew / data glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using AWS Data glue / AWS Data brew recipes for ETL for csv files that contain some interesting data. During the ingestion process, can i generate a "running id" or "unique Id" for each of the rows that are being read? Imagine that i am trying to create a record identifier for each of the rows in the brew catalog table

Any help / direction will be greatly appreciate

Thanks in advance
VJVRR

**EDIT 1 - Bumping to get more views / answers please**

Answer (score 0):

There is UUID generator that is recently released in AWS Glue visual studio which you can use or an Identifier column as shown below.[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzxZx.png)